# GCP GKE - Number of pods per Node

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a limit on number of pods per instance on GCP GKE nodes? For example I'm using `n1-standard-2` which has 2vcpu and 7.5Gb of RAM. For AWS EC2 instances, there is limit and the following formula:

```
Max Pods = Maximum supported  Network Interfaces for instance type ) * ( IPv4 Addresses per Interface ) - 1
```

Is there such a limit for GCP GKE nodes? Or is it that I can run any number of pods as long there is free resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of pods per node is set to `110`

This and other limits [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/scalability#dimension_limits)

Answer (score 4):

As per GKE's [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/quotas#limits_per_cluster)

Standard cluster: Maximum pod's per nodes is 256 [ note: For GKE versions earlier than 1.23.5-gke.1300, the limit is 110 Pods.]

Autopilot cluster: It'll dynamically adjust their count to any value between 8 and 256.
[note: For GKE versions earlier than 1.28, the limit is 32 Pods.]